# Implementing BluetoothChat in emulator

Tags: java, php, android

I want to implement the bluetooth chat in my Emulator while application running in Eclipse.
Plz help me. . .

Same way i also want to implement the Online chat threw the Emulator. 
Is it possible ?
And if it is then plz give me the Sollution for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in notepad with the same success. Android emulator has no Bluetooth support AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Budy. . . . But i want to implement the Online chat also. will u help me plz ?